# Average salary through MapReduce code

Tags: java, hadoop

Can someone please help me to find out why I am not getting the average salary after running my MapReduce code.
Problem: Calculate Average salary of permanent and contract employee

Sample Input:
    1 user1 permanent 100
    2 user2 contract  500
    3 user3 permanent 200
    4 user4 contract  300

Expected Output:
    permanent   285
    contract    187

Output I got:
    permanent 100
    permanent 200
    contract  500
    contract  300

Run Job:
    $ hadoop jar partition.jar com.hadoop.PartitionExample 
    input/partition_example.txt output

```
package com.hadoop;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;


public class PartitionExample {
        public static class MapClass extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, 
        Text, IntWritable>{

        Text outKey = new Text(); ;
        IntWritable outValue = new IntWritable();

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) 
        throws IOException, InterruptedException{
            String[] colmn = value.toString().split(" ");
            outKey.set(colmn[2]);           
            outValue.set(Integer.parseInt(colmn[3])); 
            context.write(outKey, outValue);
     }
}
// permanent      [100,300,200,400]
public static class ReduceClass extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text, 
IntWritable>{
        IntWritable outValue = new IntWritable();
        public void Reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> value, Context 
        context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
            int sum = 0; int count = 0; int avg ;
            //outKey.set(key);
            for (IntWritable sal:value){
                sum = sum + sal.get(); 
                count++;
            }
            avg = sum/count ;
            outValue.set(avg);
            context.write(key, outValue);
     }
 }

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, 
    ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException{
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
    if(otherArgs.length != 2){
        System.err.println("Number of argument passed is not 2");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    Job job = new Job(conf, "My regular MapReduce job");

    job.setJarByClass(PartitionExample.class);
    job.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);
//  job.setCombinerClass(ReduceClass.class);
    job.setReducerClass(ReduceClass.class);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake in the code. It was very silly mistake I can say :(
it was in ovirridden reduce function name. I change it from "Reduce" to "reduce".